# How to resolve the issue KeyError: "None of [Index(['date', 'username', 'message'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, whatsapp

I am trying to load my Whatsapp chats into a dataframe but it keeps throwing an error..

> text format of the chat: [16/12/2019, 08:28:33] Pastor Uba: Die! Die!

My code

```
chats = WhatsAppChat.from_source(filepath='/content/_chat.txt', hformat='%d/%m/%Y,%I:%M%p-%name:').df
```

I was expecting a dataframe with date, name, and message columns